Confused about use of random states for training models in scikit
I am new to ML and currently working on improving the accuracy of an MLPClassifier in scikit. My code looks like so
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

data = pd.read_csv("./Synthetic_data.csv", header=0)
filtered_data = data.drop(['diag_binary'], axis=1)

X = filtered_data[['sex', 'age', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q']]
y = filtered_data[['diag_multi']]

enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False)

ros = RandomOverSampler(random_state=0)
X_resampled, y_resampled = ros.fit_resample(X, y)

X_1hot = enc.fit_transform(X_resampled)

datasets = train_test_split(X_resampled, y_resampled, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

train_data, test_data, train_labels, test_labels = datasets

print(train_labels.values.ravel())

param_grid = [{'learning_rate_init': [0.01, 0.05, 0.1],
               'learning_rate': ['constant', 'adaptive'],
               'batch_size': [8, 16, 32, 64],
               'hidden_layer_sizes': [(256, 128, 64), (128, 64, 32)]}]

mlp = MLPClassifier(max_iter=1000)
grid_mlp = GridSearchCV(mlp, param_grid=param_grid, cv=5, verbose=4)

grid_mlp.fit(train_data, train_labels.values.ravel())

print(grid_mlp.score(test_data, test_labels))

So basically, I resample my data, since it is very imbalanced, I 1-hot encode my features, split the features and labels into training and test data and then perform a grid search with 5-fold cross validation to tune hyperparameters. To actually see differences in the resulting scores I use random states for my data split as well as the initialization of my MLP.
The main thing I'm wondering about is how to proceed further. Let's say I get a score on my test set that I find acceptable. In that case should I train my best model (that GridSearchCV returns) one more time without fixed random states? As I already asked a similar question earlier in this thread https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/46699/86778 I think the answer is yes, since I want my model to generalize well. But I don't understand how one more training with another random state "chosen by scikit" helps in assuring my model generalizes better. If the new state is a "good" one I would get good results but my model could still perform bad in most other states. Vice versa if the new state is a "bad" one I would get bad results but my model could still perform good in most other states. So I don't see how simply training my model one time on a new state would give me any more confidence in its ability to generalize.
To summarize my thoughts of the paragraph above into one question: If my model already generalizes well for a fixed data split and a fixed model initialization, how is training my model on a new data split and a new model initialization once, gonna help in measuring the generalizability of my model and eventually improve it? Wouldn't I need to perform several trainings with my tuned model on different splits with different model initializations to truly see how my model performs?
